# What is the origin of the idiom "get your shorts in a knot"?

Tags: meaning, idioms

I got this idiom from my English homework and still can't wrap my head around why this means "to become over upset over something, especially something unimportant."

Does anyone know where this idiom derives from?

Comment: Besides the BrE answer, the AmE phrase is: get your panties in a wad. Think about it, haven't you ever had issues with your underwear and comfort?

Comment: "Surveys have established that between 5% and 7% of men don't wear underwear (it's called “go commando” or “freeballing”)."  Anyway, the thus phrase that I remember is, "Don't get your poop in a loop."